# How to parse through a Json avoiding few elements

Tags: java, json

This is a Json which I am trying to read.

```json
{
    "total": 100,
    "withdrawal": true,
    "cliffs": [
        {
            "settings": {
                "type": "Tools",
                "url": "/se/da/v/IAF"
            },
            "Record": "IIAA1245785",
            "Mark": "U909033"
        },
        {
            "settings": {
                "type": "Tools",
                "url": "/se/da/v/IAF3"
            },
             "Record": "IIAA12467865",
            "Mark": "U7898678"
        },
        {
            "settings": {
                "type": "Tools",
                "url": "/se/da/v/IAF6675F"
            },
            "Record": "IIAA19887",
            "Mark": "U687687678"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the Record and Mark details only within the cliffs.

I am currently doing this

```
String response = getrecords();
List<String> expectedRecord = JsonPath.read(response, "$.cliffs[*].Record");
List<String> expectedMark  = JsonPath.read(response, "$.cliffs[*].Mark");
```

Is there other way of getting Record and Mark alone within cliffs avoiding the settings block?

When I try the following:

```
List<String> expectedRecord = JsonPath.read(response, "$.cliffs[*]");
```

I get the settings block as well with the response which I don't need.

```json
{
            "settings": {
                "type": "Tools",
                "url": "/se/da/v/IAF"
            },
            "Record": "IIAA1245785",
            "Mark": "U909033"
        },
        {
            "settings": {
                "type": "Tools",
                "url": "/se/da/v/IAF3"
            },
             "Record": "IIAA12467865",
            "Mark": "U7898678"
        },
        {
            "settings": {
                "type": "Tools",
                "url": "/se/da/v/IAF6675F"
            },
            "Record": "IIAA19887",
            "Mark": "U687687678"
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what JsonPath implementation you are using. Does `$.cliffs[*].[Record, Mark]` work?